# Linearity (or lack of) of quadratic variation.

Tags: probability-theory

I initally thought that quadratic variation was linear. That is :

$\langle X+Y \rangle_t = \langle X \rangle_t + \langle Y \rangle_t$ but I am now fairly certain this is untrue, specfically letting $X=Y$ highlights a flaw as it leaves us with:

$\langle 2X \rangle_t = 2\langle X \rangle_t $ but this is untrue when trying to make $4X^2$ a martingale.

I now think that

$\langle X+Y \rangle_t = \langle X \rangle_t + \langle Y \rangle_t + 2\langle X,Y \rangle_t$

Just from observing the deffinitions of quadratic varitaion in terms of its limiting sum.

Also we should note that letting $Z = X+Y$ we expect $Z^2_t  - \langle X+Y \rangle_t $ to be a martingale and we indeed are left with

$(X^2_t-\langle X \rangle_t )  +  ( Y^2_t-\langle Y \rangle_t ) + 2 ( XY_t - \langle X,Y \rangle_t ) $

Is everything sound? Any conditions for the linerarity to hold? i.e what is it called when proccesses have $\langle X,Y \rangle _t = 0? $

Comment: You should think of $\langle X\rangle_t$ as $\langle X,X\rangle_t$. Then $\langle 2X\rangle_t=\langle 2X,2X\rangle_t=4\langle X,X\rangle_t=4\langle X\rangle_t$ and all is fine.

Comment: @KurtG. super!!

Comment: You are welcome. Note that *variation* $\langle X\rangle_t$ has a lot to do with *variance*. Likewise, *covariation* $\langle X,Y\rangle_t$ with *covariance*. And they behave as such when it comes to bi-linearity. In a sense, the $\langle.,.\rangle$ notions are the variance/covariance that you could estimate when someone gives you a historical time series of $X$ and $Y$.